# Can't access checkbox values in gridview on postback

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

This sounds a lot like a bunch of other questions on here, but nothing I've read follows what I'm seeing.

I have a gridview that contains a number of bound fields and a couple of template fields containing checkboxes.  The gridview is bound to a custom datasource on pageload (inside a "not page.ispostback()" condition). The user can check the checkboxes to specify certain actions that are then committed when a link button is clicked.

The link button's click event has the following code in it:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In UnpaidEntriesGridView.Rows
    Dim paidCheckbox As CheckBox = CType(row.FindControl("PaidCheckbox"), CheckBox)
    If paidCheckbox.Checked Then
        // perform database action
    End If
Next
Initialise() // (this rebinds the gridview)
```

No matter what I do, I cannot get hold of the checked value of any checkbox in the gridview that the user has changed.  All checkboxes remain in their original state (set on data bind).

This is more than likely a page life-cycle issue, but for the life of me, I can't figure out why the user's changes aren't persisted after postback, despite the fact that the gridview isn't rebound until after I've checked.

ViewState is enabled, everything's pretty standard here otherwise.

Gridview code snippet from ascx follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="UnpaidEntriesGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EnableViewState="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Entry Name" DataField="EntryName" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="PaidCheckbox" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:LinkButton ID="UnpaidEntriesSaveLinkButton" runat="server" Text="Commit Changes" />
```

Any help (even a slap for being so stupid) would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Sounds trivial, but have you checked that the Grid is not getting databound just before the button click event? Is the Grid's datasource set through the code or object data source? Also, have you debugged it using breakpoints?

Comment: Are you missing if(!IsPostBack) condition where you are assigning DataSource to your grid?

Comment: Definitely got a Not IsPostBack condition; datasource is set through code and have debugged with breakpoints with no success.  Actually set a breakpoint in the databound event of the gridview, which doesn't fire before the button click event. Am I right in thinking that means that the gridview isn't being re-bound?

Comment: Do you have a master page? By any chance, are you doing Page.DataBind() in the master page Page_Load function? If so, do you want to try by removing that line from there?

Comment: Could you show the markup for one of the CheckBoxes (or just the whole TemplateField that it's in)?

Comment: There is a master page, but this code is actually in a user control, so the master page knows nothing about it (pretty much). Will add code from ascx to post.